# Data Connectivity and Performance

Tags: oracle, networking, virtual-machine, windows-server-2016, exadata

I have a Tableau Data Extract that refreshes on a schedule. Our Tableau Production Server is on-promise, and when I run this extract on the Tableau Production Server, it takes forever to finish. There is another server VM (let's call VM 'X') which is at the same location as the Tableau Production Server. When I run the extract from this machine, it finishes in 10 minutes. Our data lake is in Oracle Exadata.

**What I have tried so far:**

- I ran the Trace Route which didn't help much.
- I thought it might be a traffic issue as Tableau Production Server is usually pretty busy. So, I went to our Tableau Dev Server VM which at the same location, and ran the extract there. It takes same time as production server.

Any ideas on what else I can try before reaching out to our networking team?

Comment: You statements are unclear: is the "server VM which is at the same location as the Tableau Server" your Dev Tableau server that you mention later, or something else. Is "10 minutes" faster, slower, or the same as the production Tableau server? OS and other software can make a difference too: if your Tableau servers (on Windows) are running a virus scanner like McAfee, that will impact your disk I/O drastically. If Tableau is always slow and other clients are faster, consider what they are _doing_ with the data as they receive it. Also have the DBA check the performance of the query in the DB.

Comment: It's a Windows Server VM different from both Tableau Prod or Dev server VMs.

Comment: Still don't know if it's faster, slower, or the same as the others. My personal experience is that the problem is almost _never_ the actual network throughput; it isn't impossible, but other resources like CPU load or disk I/O are much more likely culprits - especially since Tableau will be saving a local copy of the data. Have you done any monitoring of the Tableau server or database server to determine if there's a resource issue with either?